# Can I use more than one ads api ( sdk ) in my application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ads, ads-api

I am developing a game in which I have some game play screens, game info screens and game finish screens.

I want to show the ads from admob on info/playing screen and from greystripe or mobclix before the results screen comes.

I am curious for knowing, if it can be done (The app will not be rejected by apple ?)

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: also throw in some iAds to appease them ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be done. One example of this is the "Touch Tanks" app as well as other apps from same company.

This does however not guarantee that it will not get rejected by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can be done. 
You might also want to take a look at adwhirl (supports rotating ad systems)